# why the new created virtualenv includes python ros package?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment with `virtualenv python3.7_env`. after `source home/${username}/python3.7_env/bin/activate`. i checked the current python version and pip version with `which python` and `which pip`, the environment seems to be ran normally as follows.

```
(python3.7_env) jin@jin-t480:~/python3.7_env/bin$ which python
/home/jin/python3.7_env/bin/python
(python3.7_env) jin@jin-t480:~/python3.7_env/bin$ which pip
/home/jin/python3.7_env/bin/pip
(python3.7_env) jin@jin-t480:~/python3.7_env/bin$ pip list
Package                         Version
------------------------------- -------
actionlib                       1.11.16
angles                          1.9.12
base-local-planner              1.14.8
bondpy                          1.8.3
camera-calibration              1.12.23
camera-calibration-parsers      1.11.13
catkin                          0.7.20
controller-manager              0.13.5
controller-manager-msgs         0.13.5
controller-manager-tests        0.13.5
cv-bridge                       1.12.8
...
...
wheel                           0.35.1
wiimote                         1.13.0
xacro                           1.11.3
```

why the virtualenv includes ros-packages?

Comment: What is the content of `python3.7_env/pyvenv.cfg`?

Comment: ```home = /usr
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.7.9.final.0
virtualenv = 20.1.0
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /usr
base-exec-prefix = /usr
base-executable = /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: OK. Then I do not understand. If you had `include-system-site-packages = true` that could have been an explanation, but it is not the case. Is this something that you can reproduce every time? Maybe edit your question to show the verbose output of `virtualenv -vvv new_env`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it by removing

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

line from my `.bashrc`. Now my `venv`s are normal again.